# In Ada, how do I get the current time in seconds as a value I can print out and perform operations with?

Tags: time, ada, seconds

I am doing a project for an operating systems class. I need to write a program that prints out the current time every ten seconds but also accounts for the delay of the overhead so that it does not drift when it has been running for a long time. I need it to be up to at least 1 decimal place as well.

I am stuck on step 1 as I can't figure out how to get the current time in seconds as a value. I have searched but could only find out how to get the current time in the HH:MM:SS format.

Thanks

Comment: You should post your code here. Check the guides [ask] and [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Did you look at the definitions of [Ada.Calendar](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-9-6.html) and [Ada.Real_Time](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-D-8.html)?  Can you explain why the operations in that package aren't good enough for what you need?

Comment: I know I'm probably missing something obvious but I don't see a way to get out a value from those definitions.

Comment: What do you mean by a "value"?  If you're trying to return the "current time in seconds" as a single number, you need to realize that there is no such thing, unless it's in relation to some other point in time, i.e. "the number of seconds since some particular point in time (e.g. midnight of January 1, 1970).  If that's what you need, that can be obtained easily from `Ada.Calendar`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

`writing_test.ads`

```ada
package Writing_Test is

    protected Writer is
        entry write( Text : String; New_Line : Boolean:= True );
    end Writer;

    task Timer is
        entry Start;
        entry Pause;
        entry Stop;
    end Timer;


private

    Timer_Frequency : constant Duration:= 10.0;

end Writing_Test;
```

`writing_test.adb`

```ada
with
Ada.Calendar,
Ada.Text_IO;

package body Writing_Test is

    protected body Writer is
        entry write( Text : String; New_Line : Boolean:= True ) when True is
        begin
            Ada.Text_IO.Put( Text );

            if New_Line then
                Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
            end if;
        end;
    end Writer;

    task body Timer is
        Active,
        Stop_Task : Boolean:= False;

        Next_Time : Ada.Calendar.Time;
        use type Ada.Calendar.Time;
    begin
        MAIN:
        loop
            if not Active then
                select
                    accept Start do
                        Active:= True;
                        Next_Time:= Ada.Calendar.Clock + Timer_Frequency;
                    end Start;
                or
                    terminate;
                end select;
            else
                select
                    accept Pause do
                        Active:= False;
                    end Pause;
                or
                    accept Stop do
                        Stop_Task:= True;
                    end Stop;
                or
                    delay until Next_Time;
                end select;

                exit MAIN when Stop_Task;

                if Active then
                    declare
                        Use Ada.Calendar;
                        Now : Time renames Clock;
                        Str : String renames
                          Day_Duration'Image( Ada.Calendar.Seconds(Now) );
    --' Formatter-correction trick
                    begin
                        Writer.write(Text => Str);
                        Next_Time:= Next_Time + Timer_Frequency;
                    end;
                end if;
            end if;        
        end loop MAIN;

    end Timer;

end Writing_Test;
```

Comment: You’ve answered the whole class question (rather than just the question the OP actually asked). Also, isn’t it a bounded error to call `Text_IO` within a protected operation?

Comment: Yes, it is a bounded error; also I'm not sure I did answer correctly: this may 'drift' for some definition -- because it resets to 10s after the operation completes rather than always executing at `Start+(n*10)`{n in Integer}.

Comment: Yes, both the remarks are true. Potentially blocking call in a protected operation is an error (see rm 9.5.1 Protected Subprograms and Protected Actions). Also, This program drifts, you should edit it so Next_Time is always computed from the start time.

Comment: I doubt that this program drifts.  1: The timing part is straight by the book.  2: The time related types in Ada are all fixed-precision types.  (But I am of course open to an explanation of _why_ it is drifting.)

Comment: @Jacob, I changed it: the assignment after Writer.Write was:  
Next_Time:= Now + Timer_Frequency;

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple program that does the "print every 10s" part of the job. You could easily use this code in a separate package.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Calendar;

procedure Periodic_Printer is

   task type My_Printer_Task is
   end My_Printer_Task;

   task body My_Printer_Task is
      use Ada.Calendar; -- for the "-" and "+" operations on Time
      Start_Time : Ada.Calendar.Time;
      Next_Cycle : Ada.Calendar.Time;
      Period     : constant Duration  := 10.0;
   begin
      Start_Time := Ada.Calendar.Clock;
      Next_Cycle := Start_Time;
      loop
         Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(Duration'Image(Ada.Calendar.Clock - Start_Time)); --'
         -- You could use Next_Cycle instead of Ada.Calendar.Clock - Start_Time
         -- so the printing does not depend of the time needed to do the elapsed
         -- time calculation

         delay 3.0; -- like a long operation, takes time......
                    -- This pattern assumes the each cycle last less than Period
                    -- If you cannot ensure that, you should consider improving
                    -- the pattern or reduce the computation load of each cycle

         Next_Cycle := Next_Cycle + Period;
         delay until Next_Cycle;
      end loop;
   end My_Printer_Task;

   Printer : My_Printer_Task;
begin
   delay 90.0; -- You can do your 'real work' here.

   -- Unclean way to terminate a task, you should consider improve it for a
   -- real world scenario
   abort Printer;

   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("End of program");
end Periodic_Printer;
```